# how to set java system property from linux(debian)

Tags: java, linux, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to set java system property as mentioned here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdepe

So for example to set the property:
javax.net.ssl.keyStore

I am doing:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/jira/jre/lib/security
```

Nothing seems to happen when I do the above and just get the java usage instructions:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

Can anyone tell me how to set up the java system property from linux command line?

Comment: The `java` command starts a Java program. Your command line does not supply any class that should be started.

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: If you see Usage instructions after issuing command, `It's a syntax error`.